# Update VOS 6.1.6 using Jena without loading to memory by invoking Sparql endpoint

Tags: sparql, jena, virtuoso

If I run `DELETE`/`INSERT` query from the SPARQL endpoint, the `UPDATE` operation works. The SPARQL query is

```
SELECT ALL
INSERT DATA  INTO <PERSONGRAPH>  { personURI rdf:type   foaf:Person }
```

Is it possible to do the same operation using Java code (either Jena or `VirtuosoExecutionFactory`), such that the `UPDATE` operation happens without needing to load the entire graphs into memory? I would like to invoke SPARQL endpoint from code to do the `UPDATE` operation. Please correct me if the assumption that the entire triples of a graph will be loaded in memory is wrong. The following Jena code works, but it loads the entire model to memory which causes the machine to not work when the triple size grows above 50,000.

```
SELECT ALL
String queryString1 = " INSERT DATA  { personURI 
                rdf:type   foaf:Person } "; 

UpdateRequest request1 = UpdateFactory.create(queryString1);
         UpdateAction.execute(request1, personModel);
```

I would like to do the same by invoking `sparqlService` or using `createServiceRequest` so that it avoids loading the entire graph into memory similar to the way it works for SPARQL endpoint.

The following code is not updating the Virtuoso store.

```
  SELECT ALL
    String queryString1 = " INSERT DATA  { personURI 
                    rdf:type  foaf:Person } ";

    com.hp.hpl.jenafix.query.Query query1 = com.hp.hpl.jenafix.query.QueryFactory.create(queryString1);
             com.hp.hpl.jenafix.query.QueryExecution qexec1 = com.hp.hpl.jenafix.query.QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://IP:8890/sparql", query1);
```

I have tried using `VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService`, `QueryExecutionFactory.createServiceRequest` and `QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService`. These work for `SELECT` but not for `UPDATE`. Please let me know how to do update by invoking the SPARQL endpoint from Java code. Any suggestions, tips are much appreciated.

*For new StackOverflow users there is a restriction of 2 URLs. Sadly `personUri` is an URL and can't be mentioned due to restriction. I am mentioning the `personUri` here for completeness. `personUri` is http://onmobile.com/umdb/person/juhi_chawla_268e7a02-8737-464f-97f8-172961d3335b*

Based on Andy's feedback tried using both suggestions of `UpdateExecutionFactory` and Http Client.

On trying to use `UpdateExecutionFactory` and Http Client, got `Connection refused` problem while performing `UPDATE` but not on doing `SELECT`. Proxy Host and port are already set.

Thank you for the comment. The `INSERT` syntax works for [Virtuoso Open Source](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSIndex) which is the store that is being used. I have problem using the `UpdateExecutionFactory`. I tried with the following

```
String queryString =  "DELETE DATA FROM <PERSONGRAPH> {  <"
                    + personURI
                    + "> rdf:type   foaf:Person } ";
            com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateRequest request = com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateFactory.create(queryString);
            UpdateProcessor proc = UpdateExecutionFactory.createRemote(request, "http://IP:8890/sparql");
proc.execute();
```

and got the following error stacktrace

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to IP:8890 refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at org.openjena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpPost(HttpOp.java:208)
    at org.openjena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpPost(HttpOp.java:154)
    at org.openjena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpPost(HttpOp.java:128)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.modify.UpdateProcessRemote.execute(UpdateProcessRemote.java:60)
```

Could it be possible that Virtuoso has a different URL endpoint for update?

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I used the solution of using the VirtuosoUpdateRequest and VirtuosoUpdateFactory to perform the update and it worked for me. I am not able to vote up as I don't have the required 15 reputations.

Answer (score 2):

An update is not a query in SPARQL.

Use

```
UpdateExecutionFactory
```

To stream data to the server, simply open an HTTP POST connection with content type `application/sparql-update`, and write the update (with large data) into the stream.

BTW:

```
INSERT DATA  INTO <PERSONGRAPH>
```

isn't legal SPARQL Update syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow your question.  It's not clear what was added after AndyS' response, and what was there to start with.  His note about your syntax error is probably worth more study, if you haven't resolved this yet -- and if you have, an update sharing that resolution would be a good idea.

I'd also recommend reviewing the documentation regarding [Jena connections to Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider).

Also worth noting -- questions specifically regarding Virtuoso are generally best raised on the [public OpenLink Discussion Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/), the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=virtuoso-users), or through a [confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to update data directly on server side without loading to local client memory.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            String url;
            if(args.length == 0)
               url = "jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111";
            else
               url = args[0];

            VirtGraph set = new VirtGraph (url, "dba", "dba");

            String str = "CLEAR GRAPH <http://test1>";
            VirtuosoUpdateRequest vur = VirtuosoUpdateFactory.create(str, set);
            vur.exec();                  

            str = "INSERT INTO GRAPH <http://test1> { <http://aa> <http://bb> 'cc' . <http://aa1> <http://bb> 123 . <http://aa1> <http://bb> 124 . <http://aa1> <http://bb> 125 .  }";
            vur = VirtuosoUpdateFactory.create(str, set);
            vur.exec();
```

Look at [VirtuosoSPARQLExample8.java](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaSPARQLExample8) and [VirtuosoSPARQLExample9.java](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaSPARQLExample9) in [Virtuoso Jena Provider examples](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider).